# Adding a default billing contact for an Apple Pay request

Tags: swift, applepay, passkit

I'm building an app that uses Apple Pay and as you can see below, when I display the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`, it's not getting the current user's billing address and email. If the user has used Apple Pay before, they are likely have this data *somewhere*. I see in the docs there is a `PKContact` variable on `PKPaymentRequest`.

Is there a way to get this data and pre-fill it for the first time user of my app?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users have to enter that information themselves in the iOS Settings app. Then it should be automatically filled out for *all* websites, apps, ec. that support Apple Pay.

To do this, simply:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Tap "Wallet & Apple Pay"
3. From there, simply add a credit or debit card, then fill out the default information. Now it should appear automatically in any transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The billing address and email are linked to an Apple ID.

The user can add these details themselves by going to Settings -> Wallet and Apple Pay -> add details and they will be saved for all purchases